# For what tools in ArcMap is the Export Script option active?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcmap

What tools allow you to export scripts?

[image]

I am assuming that these script would be blank python scripts.  I have not found a single tool where this option is active in my installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Script Tools" have the export option. Notice the icon change from a hammer-like icon to a scroll-like icon.

Comment: Also, you can export almost any function to a script if you first insert it into Modelbuilder. However, after that model-to-script translation you might need to do some manual adjustments.